# Pyinstaller: using the same .spec file, choose show or not show console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller 5.13.2 for a Pyqt5 application and I want that the final release has no console, but for debug purposes, I want to show the console automatically for develop branch and release candidates.

I don't want to use different .spec files to ensure release candidates and final release will give the same output (except for the console).

I tried to use --console argument in the command, but it does not work with .spec files.

Any idea? Update pyinstaller to 6.2.0 will help?

Comment: That's not clear. You build a gui app with Pyinstaller ?

Comment: Yes, an app with pyqt5

Comment: So to have an output in console, you can run the app from console

Comment: Maybe, but I want to show it automatically.

Comment: "I want that pyinstaller output has no console" and "I want to show it"...

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear enough, I will to edit it.

Comment: Running the app from console does not work, app console not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I added an argument in the spec file to change the value of `console` in the EXE object. Add arguments are not implemented in PyInstaller 5.13.2, it was implemented in 6.0.0.
An example of adding arguments to a spec file can be found in [PyInstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/v6.2.0/spec-files.html#adding-parameters-to-spec-files).